# How to automatically add a checklist to new github PR's?

Tags: github

When a Github pull request is created, it would be very nice to have a (code review) checklist added automatically to the PR. This could then be filled out by the PR submitter, and the reviewers would be able to see that the submitter has done what he is supposed to do before sending for review.

Is that possible somehow?

The best solution would be that the checklist showed up automatically when the PR was created. The second best could be an automatic comment added right after the PR was made.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` file to the root of your repo and it will be used as the template for new pull requests. You can use Github-flavored markup in that file.

So, in your template file, just add whatever markup you want. For a checklist:

```
Doneness:
- [ ] Testing
- [ ] Documentation
```

There's also an `ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md` file that does the same thing, but for new issues.

Official post: https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates

Answer (score 0):

This is possible as suggested by @james but one of the problems with this is that the checklists aren't blocking.

If you need a blocking checklist i.e. a checklist that stops the PR from merging you can use Github actions this gives you the flexibility to add conditions too - so the checklist only appears in certain contexts but the process is kind of clunky and hard to test.

There are a couple of tools in the Github marketplace though that solve for this problem (Full disclosure I built Pull Checklist so I'm a bit biased!). One is [Pull Checklist](https://www.pullchecklist.com/) and the other is [Pull Request Checklist Buddy](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CB/pages/3438346241/Online+Checklist+Editor)