# Github PR checklist

Tags: github

#### I need a checklist when someone opens a PR.

I followed [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272215/how-to-automatically-add-a-checklist-to-new-github-prs), [THIS](https://github.com/blog/2111-issue-and-pull-request-templates) and [THIS](https://jemurai.com/2019/08/15/github-pr-checklist/) instructions.

I initially added the files into a `new_branch` and created a `even_newer_branch` with a silly addition just to open a PR into the `new_branch`.

It's not working. Is it because that file should be in `master`??

THank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same problem:
Once `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md` or any of the other options listed in the links provided, is in the `master branch`, it works!